# How can I my external app collect data from games (sim racing)?

Tags: database, external, shared-memory, logfile

I'm doing a project where I need some informations from the game like:

- car model
- tires
- suspension....

So I'm developing an app that is based on cloud and I need to somehow transfer data from the game to my app. Maybe using APIs, Shared Memory, Log Files??

List of games that I need the data from:

- Asseto Corsa
- F1 2018,2019,2020...
- iRacing
- Project cars 1&2
- Automobilista

Any protocols that I can use?

https://www.simracingtelemetry.com/
This is an app that does what I need to do

I haven't really tried anything yet, I'm stuck :(

Comment: You need to find out from the game developers / documentation whether those games provide an API. When I googled `Asseto Corsa API` this was the first page I found. What language will you be developing your app in? https://github.com/ckendell/ACAppTutorial/blob/master/ACAppTutorial.md